# MS Access image attachment flicker

Tags: image, ms-access, attachment, flicker

I have a form (MS Access) which manages image attachments and a couple of reports which display those attachments based on various selection criteria. All of the image files (.jpg ) are kept to a maximum size of 1.4Mb. The form shows only one image at a time and as I move to each record, the new image flickers - usually displaying, clearing then displaying again. Occasionally the image displays just once but there seems to be no correlation between this behaviour and image size - the smaller attachments usually suffer the same effect and the larger attachments sometimes display once without flickering. There appears to be some phase issue between form display and image display but I am only guessing.

In the reports, there is no flicker on initial display and as long as I don't use the scroll bar up/down arrows or drag the slider, any refresh is acceptable (certainly not slick but I can live with that). Clicking on the scroll bar region either side of the slider, the refresh is acceptable (not slick). Using the slider or the arrows, things get unacceptably strobic.

I have searched online for "MS ACCESS", Attachment, Image, Flicker several times but all I can find are articles on flickering forms, which is not a problem in this application running on Windows 10 64-bit, plenty of memory, 2Gb graphics.  I can't find anything relevant to image attachment flicker.

My main concern is to improve the usability of the form; for the reports, careful advice not to drag the slider or use the scroll bar arrows will be enough, at a pinch.

In the context of my current application, this isn't a huge problem since image attachments are not a critical requirement. All the same, I would like to know of any way to stop the flicker for anything in the future where it is more important.

**Edit, following further investigation prompted by suggestions below.**

I played around with putting .visible = false and .visible = true into various event handlers but with not much change, except to make the flickering worse with at least one combination. I'm not sure what code I could provide to help you suggest anything but the following might be of use:

The form's record source is a single table which provides one field "imagelink" of data type attachment, plus two text fields: "description" (short text) and "comments" (long text). In addition, the form has three combo boxes. Two of these have a row source of simple SQL on one parent table each, tblSite and tblSpecies, with the foreign key hidden in both cases, just tbleSite.sitename and tblSpecies.commonname visible in the combo boxes. The third combo box has a simple SQL row source on one table (tblColour) which is a child of tblSpecies, constrained by a WHERE clause to offer only those colour types applicable to the current species. Apart from a Delete button, that is it.

I put some MsgBox traces into several event handlers to see what was happening. I used MsgBox rather than the debugger as I wanted to see the events and the behaviour on screen at the same time (Access noob). This is what happened, with **no** .Visible = False/True code active:

**On firing up the form from scratch:**

No image visible

Form_Open

Form_Load

attImage_AttachmentCurrent

Form_Current

The image appears, no flicker

Detail_Paint (twice)

**On subsequently going to the next record via the navigation buttons:**

Detail_Paint

First image blanks

Detail_Paint

First image reappears

Detail_Paint

First image blanks

Detail_Paint

Next (second) image appears

Detail_Paint (three times)

Second image blanks

Detail_Paint

Second image reappears

attImage_AttachmentCurrent

Form_Current

Detail_Paint

Second image blanks

Detail_Paint

Second image reappears

Detail_Paint

Second image blanks

Detail_Paint

Second image reappears

The sequence above occurs every time I move from one record to another. There will no doubt be other events; I have traced only what I thought to be the most relevant.

Further, while staying on any one record but changing focus between the various text and combo boxes via mouse clicks, this happens:

Detail_Paint

Image blanks

Detail_Paint

Image reappears

There is also a Delete button on the form, which occasionally (I haven't yet tried to trace this) causes the image to flicker as the mouse passes over it - I suspect lots of Detail_Paint events. That doesn't always happen - I could do some more tracing if required but I feel I am missing some very simple, obvious point (Access noob, as already said).

The only other event code I have is:

After Update on site and species, to ensure that only one or the other is not null and to enable/disable the other combo boxes accordingly (an image can be of an insect or a site, not both, a colour can only be assigned to an already selected species). The After Update on species also resets the Colour combo box row source to restrict the colours to those relevant for the new species.

It feels to me that setting .visible = False on leaving a record, then .visible = True once the new record has settled down, might work. However, I can't see any suitable Detail event that could do this. On_Next_Record_Click and On_Current_Record_Finshed_Doing_Stuff would help but there are no such things as far as I can see.

If there is any of the existing code you think might be of use, I can attach details. I still have some hair left. I apologise for anything silly I have done but event processing was never my strength - give me procedures, please.

Comment: `myimage.visible = false` once you start loading the record and then `myimage.visible = true` when loading is finished. this should prevent flickering. The excat place where to put these instructions is impossible to tell because you havent shown any code.

Comment: I don't now if that would be an option for you, but I have never used attached images, instead using either filenames that correlate to ids or text fields with the filenames and simply assigning those to the proper controls for display. Never had issues with flickering even with old slow computers.

Comment: Thomas G, please have a look at the edit. SunKnight0, I will look at that as an option if I can't fix the attachments.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my database where when I went from one record to another the photo attachment would flicker. I used the application.echo property and turned it off on the current event code, but was still having the problem.

I realized that it was running through an after update event as well, but when I turned the application.echo off on that code it eliminated the flicker.

Make sure to turn the application.echo back on at the end of each Subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the screen from flickering in moving on a form from one attachment to the next, you could combine the Attachment control’s KeyDown event with the Timer event for the form.

I achieved the desired result by turning screen repainting off on the Attachment control’s KeyDown event and by turning it on again when the Form's Timer occurs.  The form's TimerInterval property specifies the interval between Timer events. In my case, one millisecond was sufficient to prevent flickering.

```
Private Sub Attachment_Artwork_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)    
  If 33 = KeyCode Or _
     34 = KeyCode Or _
     37 = KeyCode Or _
     38 = KeyCode Or _
     39 = KeyCode Or _
     40 = KeyCode Then Application.Echo False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
  Application.Echo True
End Sub
```